# Objective C regex for currency validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, uitextfield

I have a input field for amount, in which user should be allowed to enter minimum value of Rs.10 and maximum of Rs.99999, i.e Length of input string has a range between 2 and 5. I wish to have a check If a user has entered invalid numbers e.q 01,002,9999999,030. These are all invalid should not accepted.

Here is my sample code:

```
if ([amount.text length]>=2 && [amount.text length]<=5) {
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

Comment: The OP asks about regex but nowhere mentioned this in his post. 
Updates - Updated formatting and language to convey the best possible intent in original question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can check this value with a [`^[1-9][0-9]{1,4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/kI9cS2/1) regex:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[1-9][0-9]{1,4}$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, amount.text.length);
NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:amount.text options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:textRange];
// Did we find a match?
if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
              if ([amount.text length]>=2 && [amount.text length]<=5) 
    {
    }
     else
      {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Plz enter the amout Min 10Rs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
      }


}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
              if ([amount.text length]>=10 && [amount.text length]<=9999) 
    {
    }
     else
      {
        UIAlertView *alertdemo = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"please enter the amount Min 10Rs and Max amount 9999" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertdemo show];
        return;
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to perform validation inside `textFieldDidEndEditing`. because `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` call every time you changed character.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([textField.text integerValue]<10 || [textField.text integerValue]>99999) {

        UIAlertView *alertdemo = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"please enter the amount Min 10Rs and Max amount 9999" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertdemo show];
    }


}
```